# how to create a multiple-dim list like this DATA<-list(list(list(),list(),list()),list(list(),list(),list()),list(list(),list(),list()))?

Tags: r

I want to pre-define a list like this using R

```
DATA<-list(
 list(list(),list(),list()),
 list(list(),list(),list()),
 list(list(),list(),list())
)
```

how to write it more concise? What if I want create a very huge Recursive list? This seems like a little easy, but I've been thinking a lot...

Comment: how deep is the list? what parameters do you specify? maybe a multi-dim array is what you really want?

Comment: @qwr I want to create a list with dim=c(5,3,3,4) in my project, but the question can be extension to any dimension. And my smallest element is also a list that store my datasets with different data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try define a custom function `nestLst` with `Reduce` to create the nested list, e.g.,

```
nestLst <- function(dims) {
  Reduce(
    function(x, n) replicate(n, x, simplify = FALSE),
    append(list(list()), as.list(rev(dims)))
  )
}
```

where you only need to pass the dimensions of the desired nested list to the function.

---

**Example**

```
> nestLst(dims = c(2,3,2))
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
list()

[[1]][[1]][[2]]
list()


[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]][[1]]
list()

[[1]][[2]][[2]]
list()


[[1]][[3]]
[[1]][[3]][[1]]
list()

[[1]][[3]][[2]]
list()



[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
list()

[[2]][[1]][[2]]
list()


[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]]
list()

[[2]][[2]][[2]]
list()


[[2]][[3]]
[[2]][[3]][[1]]
list()

[[2]][[3]][[2]]
list()
```

Comment: However, why does R not have such a simple function?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `replicate()` here.

```
DATA <- replicate(3, replicate(3, list(), simplify = FALSE), simplify = FALSE)
```

We replicate a list three times and then replicate that three times.

Comment: straightforward solution, +1!

Comment: Good solutions! Thanks for your answer! It really worked!

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, you may actually want to use a [multi-dimensional array](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/array.html) instead of a multi-level list. Especially if you want to use matrix or vector operations, it is much simpler to use.

```
data <- array(dim=c(5,3,3,4))
```

This array can be indexed using all of R's indexing capabilities, for example `data[1,1,,]`.